# Multiline CATextLayer with truncation

Tags: iphone, ios, truncation, catextlayer

Is there a way to make a CATextLayer show the "..." if I have wrapped == YES?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm running into this issue at the moment.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes, set truncationMode = kCATruncationEnd. It defaults to kCATruncationNone.

Comment: Have you tested this? When I tested before the OP I found this did not work.